# jQuery find not working with attributes selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a form in which:

- `$('form').find('input[type=submit]')` gives `[undefined]`
- but `$('form input[type=submit]')` works as expected...

Is it normal?

Comment: If you want anyone to take your question seriously, include your full code.

Comment: It works! Provide example replicating your issue

Comment: As I see two variants works http://jsbin.com/ticoci/1/edit?js,console

Comment: it must not...just inspect element this page ...put your `$('form').find('input[type=submit]')` in console you will see your code is working fine

Comment: @helpYou Votes have nothing to do with hate. This question is low quality. If anything, people who _don't_ down-vote are the bane of SO.

Comment: @lajarre Usually down voters win

Comment: @helpYou This question contains only a small portion of the related code, there's no DOM sample on which the problem can be replicated.

Comment: @helpYou Hardly. It's the duty of the asker to make the question clear, not the job of people answering to figure out the problem. The help center is very clear on this if you have any further confusion.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Rough average age of a grass leaf: 35 years (according to a random Google search). Trees can live up to thousands of years. Your point is wrong and moot.

Comment: @Nit I don't want to get too much involved, that's why I've written "Is it normal" as an equivalent to "did it happen to anyone already?". I won't post my full code because this is not worth it for me right now (too much JS involved), but I will maybe try to boil the code down to the essence of the problem one day...

Comment: @lajarre: Use a JavaScript debugger to test your code. First add a watch for `$` to verify jQuery loaded, then a watch for `$('form').length` to verify that a `FORM` element was found, then add a watch for `$('form').find('input[type=submit]').length` to verify that the `INPUT type=submit` element was found. (`length` properties should be `> 0`). You can do similar tests for `$('form input[type=submit]')` to try to figure out why one selector works and the other does not (which I have not seen before).

Comment: @lajarre You don't need to post all of your code. You need to post all the _relevant_ pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

Both works properly

```js
console.log($('form').find('input[type=submit]').val());
console.log($('form input[type=submit]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="submit" value="somevalue" />
</form>
```

Comment: Now WHY this has been downvoted? It answers question

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for defending. Usually down voters win

Answer (score 2):

You should show more code, but if you are getting `undefined` you may not have actually loaded the jQuery library.

If you are on Windows desktop, your browser probably has Developer Tools (usually F12) that you can use to view the JavaScript console and to debug (step through) your code as it executes.

The return value of a jQuery selector is an array, and typically to verify whether you selected a single element you need only check the length of this array (assuming that jQuery is loaded correctly, which you can test by typing `jQuery` into the console which should show `function(a,b){...}` or similar, as opposed to throwing an exception about an undefined reference).

*To test these examples, open your JavaScript / Dev Tools console first, then click Run Snippet*

**WORKING CODE (jQuery is loaded)**

```js
var $elem = $("form input[type='submit']");
if ($elem.length === 1) {
    if (console) console.log("found the element");
} else {
    if (console) console.log("did not find the element (could inject it, or log error, etc.)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit form' />
</form>
```

**NON-WORKING CODE (jQuery is NOT loaded)**

```js
try
{
var $elem = $("form input[type='submit']");
if ($elem.length === 1) {
    if (console) console.log("found the element");
} else {
    if (console) console.log("did not find the element (could inject it, or log error, etc.)");
}
}
catch (ex)
{
if(console)console.log(ex.message);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit form' />
</form>
```